# Login desde android studio a MySQL con java

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, webservice

estoy haciendo un proyecto en android studio de final de grado, necesito hacer el modelo de datos de cliente y servidor, pero solo estoy encontrando información de como conectar desde Android Studio hacia MySQL a través de WebServices pero me hacen crear un archivo .php que es el que conecta con la BBDD, pero yo quiero hacerlo todo en java, nada que ver con php.. no encuentro nada de información veo que todo el mundo utiliza PHP para hacer esto.. alguien que me pueda abrir la mente por dios xD, gracias de antemano!
(Pondré código de lo que he hecho hasta ahora y me funciona pero esta echo en php y yo lo quiero en java)

Android studio:

```
RequestQueue rq;
JsonRequest jrq;

if(!etUsername.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || !etPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                            rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                            validarUserMySQL();

private void validarUserMySQL() {
        String url = "http://192.168.0.11/login/sesion.php?username="+etUsername.getText().toString()+"&password="+etPassword.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        rq.add(jrq);
    }
```

Codigo php para hcer el login a través de los parámetros que recibe.(Utilizo xampp)

```
<?PHP
$hostname="localhost";
$database="dbmoria";
$username="";
$password="";
$json=array();
    if(isset($_GET["username"]) && isset($_GET["password"])){
        $username=$_GET['username'];
        $password=$_GET['password'];

        $conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname,"moriausr","moriapwd",$database);
        /*SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username= "borja" AND password = "12345"*/
        $consulta="SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username= '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}'";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

        if($consulta){

            if($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $json['datos'][]=$reg;
            }
            mysqli_close($conexion);
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
        else{
            $results["username"]='';
            $results["password"]='';
            $json['datos'][]=$results;
            echo json_encode($json);

        }

    }
    else{
            $results["username"]='';
            $results["password"]='';
            $json['datos'][]=$results;
            echo json_encode($json);

        }
?>
```

Resultado:

```
{"datos":[{"0":"borja","username":"borja","1":"12345","password":"12345"}]}
```

Comment: Hay algunos tutoriales de eso en internet, te puede servir: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-call-java-web-service-in-android/

Comment: Voy a mirarmelo.. gracias!

Comment: Vale esto tiene como hacer un webservice con SOAP pero como enlazo esto con MySql

Comment: Tutoriales con ese tema hay demasiados: http://tutorialspedia.com/java-jax-ws-soap-web-service-step-by-step-tutorial-for-crud-operations-using-eclipse-mysql/

Comment: ¿Por qué lo quieres en Java? ¿Es obligatorio? Si la base de datos está en un servidor, es mucho mejor usar PHP (a no ser que dicho servidor esté basado en Java).

Comment: Obligatorio no es, pero bueno lo entedería mejor ya que php sé muy poco y java pues lo domino más y tengo que decidir en hacer todo java o todo php

Comment: Si, en realidad no te puedes conectar directamente a la base de datos, por ello necesitas generar un servicio web. Ahora bien para generar el servicio dependiendo la maquina donde lo generes y que tan complejo sea puedes usar como servidor de aplicaciones JBoss, Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish (estos serían como el Apache del PHP)  generas un proyecto REST o SOAP usando Java (hay multitud de librerías pasando por Spring-WS, Jersey, Apache-CXF, etc para generar el servicio), del lado del Android le debe de dar igual si el servicio lo hiciste con Python, PHP, Java u C# u otro. Yo también usaría Java.

Comment: tambien estoy en la misma situación tenemos una aplicacion de escritorio en Java 100% conectandose a un servidor local con IP publica, necesitamos desarrollar un APK en Android Studio para que se conecten remotamente desde sus tabletas a ese servidor por medio de la IP Publica, dominamos JAVA muy bien y conectamos a ese servidor desde cualquier parte en la aplicación de escritorio, pero en el caso de androidStudio, no vemos como podemos conectarlo y se vuelve complicado un poco mas, hablan de PHP y servicios Web, etc, En nuestro caso particular todo debe ser 100% Java, nada de php, ni lenguaje

Comment: Para conectarte a una base de datos no es necesario conectarte a través de un servicio `SOAP o REST`, te puedes conectar por  `IP`, ahora bien, por más que se quiera pensar que Android es Java no lo es, porque Android no ejecuta su una JVM sino Dalvik que no es 100% compatible con Java por las limitaciones de los dispositivos móviles, para Android las comunicaciones deben de ser apoyadas por SQLLite porque JPA y JDBC son muy pesadas, esto quieres decir que proyectos como Hibernate no funcionan en Android

Comment: Algunas alternativas que hay son `OrmLite` para tener algo parecido a la persistencia o `JTDS` para conectarte a Micosoft SQL Server con JDBC, si bien conectarte directamente a una base de datos no es recomendable porque tiene muchas limitaciones para escalar, flexibilidad a los cambios y mejoras. Por ejemplo con una API puede tener una APP en Android y otra en IOS compartiendo la misma API, pero con conexión directa no puedes reutilizar código de Android en IOS,  tendrás que utilizar otra forma de conexión aparte de duplicar todo la lógica de base se datos.